# Перенос стилей makeStyles() MaterialUI в отдельный файл

Tags: reactjs, ui, style

изучаю  React, пишу свой проект для развития и резюме;) , использую Material UI. Во  время проекта, возник вопрос о структиризации папок , как мне грамотно перенести стили makeStyles в другой файл , чтобы не возникало каши в jsx компоненте? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

При использовании MaterialUL стили создаются в файле через функцию
`сonst classes = useStyles();`

вынесите создание стилей в отдельный файл и сделайте экспорт `useStyles`

Вот примерный результат:

style.js:

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    button: {
        textTransform: 'capitalize',
    },
}));
```

component.js:

```js
import useStyles from './style';
const ShareButton = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
       <Button className={classes.button}/>
    )
});
```